# Double value appending with additional 0

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

```
Double amount = 0.001
```

but amount value is set to **0.0010**

we have strict condition at the end to allow only **3 decimal places** before storing in DB. but somehow it is appending **0** at the end.

i have tried

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
 String formatedString = decimalFormat.format(amount));
```

at this point `formatedString` in 0.001 which is correct. but if i change back again to Double.

```
Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(formatedString));
```

it is again adding 0 at the end 0.0010. how to remove 0 at the end by default for type Double?

Comment: You can not force a double to have n decimal places. Simple as that.

Comment: But but... they're equal. Double are just double, they're not formatted-double.

Comment: Also... don't tag in title, and don't write in capital case. Just tagging the question with [tag:java] is enough

Comment: @user202793 My requirement is if user enters 0.0011 i should throw error instead of saving. but for 0.001 it should accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class `BigDecimal` to define the scale and the rounding mode for your needs. ie:

```
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("1.12345").setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
val.doubleValue();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: thanks this helped ! intead of round off. i have used. BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0010).stripTrailingZeros()

Answer (score 1):

As far as the Double is concerned, 0.001 and 0.0010 is the same thing. If you are storing that in the DB as double, then everything is fine and what you should be looking at is the formatting of whatever program you use to **display** the values.

Comment: My requirement is if user enters 0.0011 it should throw error instead of saving. but for 0.001 it should accept.

Comment: @Manjunath Ok then you can use your code from the question (test it!), but don't worry about a trailing zero in your output. Another option is to use BigDecimal instead of double and restrict it to three decimal places.